# parse error in json data in ajax request

Tags: php, jquery

Im getting an error 200 in my ajax request. Im wanting to post 1 value which is a email address to the page in my ajax request. Could someone tell me what is wrong

Error:

```
message=:[object Object], text status=:parsererror, error thrown:=SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
```

just changed to $.parseJSON it works with no error but the success function doiesn't alert
JQuery

```
$('#checkemail').click(function() {
    var json = $.parseJSON({ "email": $('#email').val() }); 
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://' +  location.host + '/buyme/include/getemailaddress.php',
        type:'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: json,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert( 'message=:' + msg + ', text status=:' + textStatus + ', error thrown:=' +  errorThrown); 
    }});
});
```

Comment: Could you post the JSON you are receiving?

Comment: how does the code at the server looks like, code that is responsible for sending data to the client

Comment: I haven't got that far yet I don't know how to do that at the moment. I need a json parser do. I i really need is to return a empty string that is either 'true' or 'false'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I haven't got that far yet I don't know how to do that at the moment.
>   I need a json parser do. I i really need is to return a empty string
>   that is either 'true' or 'false'

yes the piece of code you have posted expects json to be recieved from `getemailaddress.php`

in your php file try putting

```
<?php

   echo json_encode("hello");

?>
```

and most probably things will work out for you

EDIT

for example from the php script you are sending an array like

```
$responseVar = array(
                    'message'=>'some message',
                    'value'=>'some value'
                    );
```

in the success handler of your ajax request you can do something like

```
success:function(data){
 console.log(data.message);
 console.log(data.value);
}
```

Comment: so how do I access my json that i have parsed in. it woorked when i added json_encode('hello')

Comment: Yeah I got that working anything else you could show or teach me. Im just learning all this stuff I've switched from asp.net to learn PHP for a course

Comment: how do i access the parsed data of my json in my php file eg. {'email':'myemail@yahoo.com'}

Comment: for starters you can accept this answer :) and keep on reading blogs and stuff, with time we learn and with age we understand...

Comment: @KDM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799304/sending-jsonjquery-to-php-and-decoding-it

Answer (score -1):

you can access your json like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url : URL,
     data: {wis_videoId:wis_v_id},
     success: function(data){
         if(data !=''){
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              alert(obj.message)
                              alert(obj.value)
          }
       },
     error:function(request, status, error){
                    alert('', request.responseText);return false}
    });
```